# What is the relationship between taxes and annual liquidation of the markets?

Tags: taxes, stock-markets, liquidity, wealth-tax

I  read [this](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/mark-cuban-picks-apart-elizabeth-warrens-proposals-compares-her-to-trump-2019-11-11?siteid=yhoof2&yptr=yahoo) article on MarketWatch where they outline Elizabeth Warren's plan to tax the wealthy:

- 2% tax on every dollar above $50 million in assets
- 6% tax on households crossing the $1 billion threshold

In a Twitter discussion between Mark Cuban and Jason, they  suggest  that the effects of these taxes will cause an annual market/asset liquidation and discuss how it may affect the overall market.

What are the mechanics they are talking about? Why would one need to liquidate their market assets because of taxes?

Comment: Are you asking about current state, where there are end-of-year tax loss harvesting and liquidity for estimated taxes moves; or a future state where a Warren or Sanders annual asset tax of several percent would exist (where such a tax does not currently exist)?

Comment: both. what is the current state, and how would the potential future taxes affect this mechanics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://economics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Most "billionaires" have their wealth in companies that they grew into multi-billion dollar entities that they own a significant portion of.  If the government then says "you own too much - you must give us 6% of what you own", then they likely don't have enough *liquid* assets (cash) to pay that bill, so they will be forced to sell shares of that company (or give them to the government, which may result in state ownership which is a whole other pickle).

That amount of forced selling artificially increases liquidity and would drop the market price of the shares since the seller would be *highly* motivated, and buyers can be price "takers".

And that's just for *public* companies. With *private* companies, liquidity is much lower, so a forced sale could be very traumatic for private owners who might have to sell their ownership for much less that what they're truly worth (and possibly give up control in the process).

Comment: @madscientist159 You don't count a publicly traded company as private enterprise? This only affects single owners.

Comment: One thing that I don't understand: if the market for the private company is not liquid, and one is forced to sell "below value", shouldn't the wealth be measured at the actual liquidation price? You should have to sell 6% of that stock, no matter at which price (as long as it's a fair market price).

Comment: Alternately, the ultra-rich would be forced to pay themselves enough dividends to cover the tax, presumably timed so that the taxman has to account for the post-dividend price drop.

Comment: @FooBar Since this is all speculation, there's no way to know if "wealth" will be measured at enterprise value, fair market value, or something else, so it's all speculation at this point. That's another issue with the whole concept of wealth tax.

Comment: @HAEM Possibly, but that also presumes that the _company_ has enough cash to cover the tax. 6% is a lot of cash on hand for some companies.

Comment: What is all this talk of companies?  doesn't this only apply to wealthy *people*?

Comment: @opa Read the first sentence. Most billionaires' "wealth" is in companies that they own. If Jeff Bezos had to pay a 6% tax on the estimated $100 billion he owns in Amazon stock, he'd have to sell (or transfer) 6% of his ownership to pay the tax (presuming he doesn't have $6 Billion in cash or other investments)

Comment: Let's say I have $100 billion in Amazon stock, but no other liquid assets. How do I buy my $50 million mansion without selling or trading that stock? Am I getting a loan with stock as collateral? And if so, how do I make the mortgage payments? How is a tax bill different? (I'm being deliberately naive; I realize the obvious ways are that my $6 billion tax bill is probably my largest single bill for the year, and paying the tax bill doesn't give me an asset I can use for collateral.)

Comment: @chepner that's a great point. My first thought is that other items are purchased more through salary and other income (and possibly some liquidation) but it's a fair point. _Politically_ I'd argue that those purchases are your _choice_, whereas a wealth tax is not.

Comment: @chepner that seems like an interesting question all on its own. Cursory googling suggests the super-rich still take mortgages and that a lot of the transactions are off-market, so perhaps they make different deals?

Comment: @gormadoc Why sell your investments that make 10% when you can borrow at 4%?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say, but I definitely didn't say that they're selling off their stocks or ownership?

Comment: @gormadoc That was intended to be a tongue-in-cheek way to agree with you. Many wealthy still borrow money in order to keep from selling their investments.

Comment: I see, I fully agree. I think it would be interesting to have another question about that but I also have a feeling that secret and private ways to get super-expensive property might be too secret and private to know much about, as a lot of the "off-the-market" stuff was discovered with the Panama Papers.

Comment: @chepner That $50M mansion is only 0.05% of your assets, much less than the proposed 6% tax. And if you take out a mortgage, you only have to put down about $5M in cash. Even if you have to sell shares to pay the downpayment and the mortgage, it probably won't be enough volume to impact the value of the company.

Comment: @FooBar There's an infinite regress or feedback problem there: if selling your assets changes the value of the assets, you can't determine how much tax you owe until after you raise the cash to pay the tax.

Comment: @Barmar Presumably that (and other related reasons) are why tax years match calendar years but taxes are not due until April 15.  The value of the assets at year-end would be used in calculating the wealth and you can sell in the new year what would be needed to pay the bill.

Comment: @Jaquez But if the value of the asset is the selling price, how would you calculate the value at year-end? For public companies it's easy, we use the market price on Dec 31, but that doesn't work for private companies and other assets.

Comment: @Barmar Good point.  I obviously got stuck in the line of thought focusing on publicly traded shares.

Comment: I think it's all a bit premature to get worried about details like this. ATM it's just a general proposal, the details will have to be worked out if it becomes a real bill.

Comment: @chepner Choosing to trade your stock for something else seems different from having your stock just... slowly disappear by itself even if you don't do anything with it.

Comment: @Barmar On the contrary, the fact that these details don't work out nicely has the potential to make the proposal impractical, and if so, it's good to realise that as soon as possible to avoid wasting effort. (Or someone might come up with a way to make it not impractical)

Comment: @user253751 My point is that trading it *isn't* how billionaires leverage their stock to obtain cash or other assets. It's not obvious that liquidation would be a *necessary* process (though the concern is that it is the one that would be chosen) in order to pay any tax bill.